# Color scheme problem

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, physics, plot-themes

I have a problem in the color scheme in a 2D spectra.

After a lot of calculations, i can generate a picture like this

[image: Generated spectra]

in the last part using this instructions

```
ListContourPlot[dat, ContourShading -> None, 
InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
Contours -> Delete[CNTRFT[dat], Length[CNTRFT[dat]]/2 + 1/2], 
ContourStyle -> CLRFT[dat], PlotRange -> {Ran[[1]], Ran[[2]], All}, 
DataRange -> Ran, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Axes -> False]

ListDensityPlot[dat, PlotRange -> {Ran[[1]], Ran[[2]], All}, 
ColorFunction -> (Hue[.45 - #] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
DataRange -> Ran, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Axes -> False]
```

the color in the corners (aquamarine) are for zero value, blue and violet are for negative values and yellow and green for positive values.
Now i need to clean this color, because i want to train a convolutional network to identify spectra. Then I need the spectra with a color scheme with white for the zero value. I try to use diferent forms as, for example change the Hue value as

```
(Hue[.45 - #, 0 - #, 1] &)
```

or

```
(Hue[.45 - #, 0 + #, 1] &)
```

but, i only obtain the negative or positive values and zero.

[image: negative values]
[image: positive values]

I have this problem for a time and i need to continue. any suggestions?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Regards.

Comment: My interpretation of your question is that you want the function to plot as white anywhere that it is zero (or perhaps just very close to zero). Is that correct? If so, you could try something like `ColorFunction -> (If[# < 0.001, White, Hue[0.45 - #]]&)`. If you want to only replace it when it's exactly equal to zero, then you could use `# == 0` instead.

Comment: Is something like these, but I need a continuous color change. A color scheme were the white corresponds to the zero value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create color schemes with white in the middle using `Blend`:

```
sample[blendColors_] := Table[
  Blend[
   blendColors,
   Rescale[x, {-1, 1}]
   ], {x, {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}}
  ]

sample[{Red, White, Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sample[{Purple, Blue, Cyan, White, Green, Yellow, Orange}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example where I don't rely on the number of colors on either side of `White`:

```
sample[{{0.1, Purple}, {0.2, Blue}, {0.5, White}, {1, Red}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally one with values that are negative and haven't been rescaled before being passed to `Blend`:

```
Table[
 Blend[
  {{-1, Purple}, {-0.5, Blue}, {0, White}, {1, Red}},
  x
  ], {x, {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi, this is an excellent approach, but there is a problem, in the second picture the colors reverse. But  with this example I found a solution to my problem.  Thanks a lot.